# PHPMailer sending mails through addCC function if mail not exist then skip that email address

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a scenario in which I have to add multiple addresses in a carbon copy (CC) field from a PHPMailer E-mail. If an E-mail is not valid, currently mail does not get sent.

I want it so that if an E-mail address is not valid, it will skip adding that E-mail address in `$mail->addCC($cc);`, and simply send to the other recipients.

Are there any alternative ways to achieve this within PHPMailer? If so, please suggest them to me.

Comment: Are you saying that if two emails are in cc and if first email does'nt exist and second exist then mail is not going to 2nd email too

Comment: Yes it gives this - SMTP Error: The following recipients failed:

Comment: I do it like this -> AddAddress(), AddCC() and then send

Comment: Sorry but I'm confused by your question. Do you want to validate an email address before adding as a CC within PHPMailer? If email address is not valid, then do not add to CC field before sending email?

Comment: i am not validating it.. I will tell you the scenario.. I am adding multiple address as cc (a@a.com, b@a.com, c@a.com), after some time a leaves the company and its email gets expired.. so when I am again running the script all the three email address again gets added, but a@a.com id gets expired, and the email is not sent to all the three perons. I want email still to be send to other two email address.

Comment: Well technically you should be validating it. If you have an email address form a user which is no longer with the company, wouldn't it make sense to remove this from source i.e. Your CC array or whatever your using? Where do you get the CC data from?

Comment: no mechanism to remove it :(

Answer (score 0):

You can send emails to cc-recipients as to main recipients like this:

```
/* Prepare PHPMailer object */
...

/* Send email to main recipient */
...

/* Form cc array */

$ccs= [
       "FirstCC"  => "first@mail.com",
       "SecondCC" => "second@mail.com"
      ];

/* Send email to each cc as to main */

foreach ($ccs as $name => $address)
{
    $mail->clearAddresses();
    $mail->AddAddress($address, $name);
    $mail->Send();
}
```

This way will provide assurance that all valid recipients get email

Comment: I want the same email with multiple cc's

Answer (score 0):

PHPMailer automatically validates all addresses you give it. The only way you can tell if an address is actually going to be accepted is to try to send to it, and if it fails, don't try to send to it next time. If you want to send to multiple CCs (where all recipients can see all other addresses in the message), do this:

```
...
$mail->addAddress('me@example.com');
foreach ($ccs as $cc) {
    $mail->addCC($cc);
}
$mail->send();
```

`addCC` will automatically skip actually invalid addresses (returning `false` for any that are invalid), but it's not possible to establish whether addresses will be accepted for delivery at this point - you have to attempt to deliver to find out.

Comment: the whole mail sends to fail. Tested it, if in addcc there is an address which does not exis, it fails to send the whole mail.

Comment: Can you set `SMTPDebug = 2` and add the SMTP transcript to your question? If you look in the `smtpSend()` method in the PHPMailer class you'll see that it does not give up if a single recipients fails. Are you perhaps using PHPMailer's default `mail()` transport which does not have that ability?